# HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth doesn't work

Tags: bash, bashrc, bash-history

The default `.bashrc` in the standard distribution of Ubuntu 16.04 that comes with AWS has these lines:

```
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I have been running `pm2 restart myApp` and `pm2 list` repeatedly using the Up Arrow key, and the command buffer now contains nearly a hundred lines of these.

What could be wrong?

Comment: [Why does bash still keep duplicate lines with erasedups?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398763/44425)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's working as intended. `ignoredups`, implied by `ignoreboth`, doesn't add a command to history if it's the same as the immediate previous command. It doesn't look further back in history. [From the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTCONTROL):

> A value of ‘`ignoredups`’ causes lines which match the previous
> history entry to not be saved.

So, this will add `foo` twice to the history:

```
$ foo
$ bar
$ foo
```

But so will this:

```
$ foo
$ bar
$ foo
$ foo
```

The last `foo` won't be added to history, since the previous command was `foo`. Use `erasedups` in conjunction:

> A value of ‘`erasedups`’ causes all previous lines matching the
> current line to be removed from the history list before that line is
> saved.

So:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

Comment: That is the problem: it doesn't work. I run `foo` 3 times in a row, exit bash, lookup history, - and it contains 3 foo! I am using `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)` / `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)` (default on macOS Big Sur)